# C# Azure Function App behaves differently when deployed

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function App written in C# targeting netcoreapp3.1.  While it works fine when executed/debugged locally in Visual Studio, certain parts of it don't work as expected when it it deployed to Azure.

Specifically, I have code in my function file (in the main function project) which looks somewhat like this (simplified and anonymized):

```
// 'ApiAccessor' is defined in a library in a separate referenced VS project:
private ApiAccessor _apiAccessor;

public async Task InitializeAsync()
{
    _apiAccessor = new ApiAccessor();
    // This populates an IEnumerable field of the ApiAccessor class:
    await _apiAccessor.PopulateRecords(); 
}
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 0 2 * * *")] TimerInfo timer)
{
    await InitializeAsync();
    MyLoggingUtil.Log($"Count of records: {_apiAccessor.Records.Count()}");
    foreach (var record in _apiAccessor.Records)
    {
        // Do something with record.
    }
}
```

Locally, the `Records` field of my `ApiAccessor` class gets successfully populated and the count of records is nonzero; the function then continues as expected.

*But on Azure*, the `Records` field is always empty (the logger output is always `Count of records: 0`).

What could possibly cause this?  In my experience with function apps, I've experienced other types of anomalies in the past, but I've never heard of data fields not getting populated (unless the internal call to the API that retrieves the data fails, in which case I have detailed logging in place to track this and any other issues).  In this case, no errors or logged and no exceptions are thrown.

I have verified that the target platform is installed on our Azure accounts and that the configuration settings are the same as locally (`FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` is `~3`, etc.).  In addition, we have several other function apps running under the same account/subscription which aren't having this problem.

I'm not sure if this makes a difference, but all the logic is stored in a separate, referenced project in the same Visual Studio solution (the function project just contains the function definition, startup, etc.).  All the projects in the solution target netcoreapp3.1.

In addition, this function is currently hosted in a deployment slot on Azure - although I'm not sure if this should make a difference either.  (The configs and settings are the same on the slot as they are on the parent app service).

Comment: I am not great with async but I suspect it is because you aren't returning anything from IntializeAsycnc.().  Try changing the last list to return await _apiAccessor.PopulateRecords();   I think the calling method is continuing before InitializeAsync is complete.  The timing will be different in different environments

Comment: Havve you tried putting some logging in `InitializeAsync` and tracing what's happening there? Perhaps `PopulateRecords` doesn't have access to whatever it's calling to populate `Records`.

Comment: We can't really tell you what's wrong with ApiAccessor.Records without seeing its code. Once the function is triggered, it's just a regular IL code running in a process. There's nothing that would alter the behaviour of your code to an extent that could be determined from the provided sample code. Unless you override Synchronization context or something (i.e. durable functions)

Comment: Silly me!!!  The error ended up being a typo in the Azure configuration section.  The ApiAccessor was calling the wrong URL.  The dataset was empty because there simply *was* no data at that (incorrect) endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

So this "anomaly" ended up being caused by a typo on my part in the function app's Configuration blade on Azure when I was manually migrating my local function's config values in `local.settings.json`  The URL that was being called was incorrect, thus there was no data coming back.